# What does רבנן קשישאי mean?

Tags: words, translation

I'm wondering what this term "רבנן קשישאי" specifically refers to. I think it just means old Rabbis, but I'm wondering if it's a reference to a specific group.

Comment: Where did you see this expression? Why is it relevant for you?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A7%D6%B7%D7%A9%D6%B4%D6%BC%D7%81%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%81?lang=he

Comment: Based on how many times Google finds this expression, it seems to mean "the elderly Rabbis in my location (all had the custom to...)"